# How to deprecate static method in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

According to Ruby on Rails API Docs you can deprecate methods with help of method [#deprecate](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-deprecate). This is all fine.

My question is; is it possible to deprecate static methods - if so, how?

For regular methods you can just do something like this:

```
deprecate :my_method
def my_method
  # ...
end
```

Bot this gives me headache (and its not working):

```
deprecate :"self.my_method"
def self.my_method
  # ...
end
```

P.s.: I know I can raise warning from method like so:

```
def self.my_method
  ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn "the warning..."
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call deprecate on the metaclass:

```
class Test1
  def self.hello
    puts "Test1"
  end
  singleton_class.deprecate :hello
  # or
  class << self ; deprecate :hello ; end
end
```

Comment: It is important here that the deprecation occur after the method declaration, and not before.

Comment: For those wondering: This works for static __module__ methods, too! :-)